# Django RestFramework IsOwnerOrReadOnly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I create my permission class for everyone can read an object and only admin create the object. But when I log out and try to create the object, permission class allowing me. What am I missing?

`models.py`

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    content = models.TextField()
    page = models.IntegerField()
```

`views.py`

```
class BookAPIView(
        mixins.CreateModelMixin,
        generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminOrReadOnly]
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = Book.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

`permissions.py`

```
class IsAdminOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return True

        return request.user.is_staff
```

Comment: use `has_permission` instead of `has_object_permission`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overwrite `has_permission`:

```
class IsAdminOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return True

        return request.user.is_staff
```

`has_object_permission` lets you modify one existing object.